# Prove that $3^n$ is not $O(2^n)$.

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I am working on some Big oh questions and I can't seem to get how disprove them. In this case we have:

Prove that $3^n$ is not $O(2^n)$

I can see that its obvious just by looking at the two functions, but I don't know how to prove it. What are the steps one should take to approach to disprove something like this?

Thanks

Comment: Well, if $3^n$ is $O(2^n)$ then by definition...

Comment: The title and the inner body say different things (the title says "prove", the inner body says "disprove").

Comment: Several people have answered your question, so I just want to warn you about “I can see that its obvious just by looking”, which in my experience is almost always bullshit, although well-meant sincere bullshit. But if you believe it, you are probably deceiving yourself. The $O(f(x))$ notation is not simple. It has a very specific technical definition and it is very unlikely that, without more experience, you can reliably see anything about it “just by looking”. For example, it may also be obvious that $n+1$ is not $O(2^n)$ “just by looking”, but it is also false.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to argue is that there does not exist an $M$ such that $3^n \le M 2^n$ for all $n$ sufficiently large. Suppose such an $M$ existed. Then you would have that $\left(\dfrac{3}{2}\right)^n \le M$. Can you see how to proceed?

Comment: is it enough to say that as n aproaches infinity, our constant M will always be less and therefore by that logic we've disproved it?

Comment: That's more or less the correct thought process.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $3^n \in O(2^n)$. Then exists constant $C \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$, that:

$$\forall n>n_0 \; 3^n \leq 2^nC$$

But it's equal:

$$\forall n>n_0 \; (\frac{3}{2})^n \leq C$$

It isn't true, because $\lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{3}{2})^n=\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

$a(n)=O(b(n))$ means that there is a bounded function $f$ such that $a(n)=f(n)b(n)$. So if you prove that $\displaystyle{\frac{3^n}{2^n}}$, you are done.

Now,

$$\frac{3^n}{2^n}=\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n$$

And $\frac32=1.5>1$. Can you conclude? It may be more obvious if you notice that

$$\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{2n}=\left(\frac{9}{4}\right)^{n}>2^n$$

Answer (score 0):

You want to show that for every c, there exists $k$ such that $3^{n} > 2^{n}c$ when $n > k$.

Let $c$ be fixed, then as long as $\frac{3}{2}^n > c$ i.e. $n >= k > \frac{\ln{c}}{\ln(\frac{3}{2})}$. Since this exists for all $c>0$ we have that $3^{n}$ is not the same order as $2^{n}$.